# How can I read a chunked request in a middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a pretty basic Asp.net core mvc api. The requests are coming from clients I don't control. I use a middleware to log the request's body. It works fine for regular requests, but I can't get read the body if it's a chunked request. However the framework can then process it just fine and my controller's action gets called with a properly decoded payload. If I put a breakpoint in my middleware and inspect the HttpRequest, I can get to this object which seems to be what I'd want to read:

```
((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestPipeReader)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest)httpContext.Request).BodyReader)._body
```

which is of type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ChunkedEncodingMessageBody`

And if I inspect it from my action, I can see that it completed and read the amount of bytes I sent. None of that is accessible though, so how can I read it?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   //other stuff ommited
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
    app.UseEndpoints(e => e.MapControllers());
}
```

RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs

```
public class RequestLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        //httpContext.Request.Body is null
        //httpContext.Request.ContentLength is 0
        //here in debug I can see that the Http1ChunkedEncodingMessageBody _body hasn't received anything yet
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

MyController.cs

```
[Route("rest/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> CreateWidget([FromBody] WidgetModel widgetData)
    {
        //widgetData is populated correctly
        //if I inspect this.Request here, _body is marked as completed and having read 108 bytes
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Sample request captured with fiddler

```
POST http://mywidgetapi.mycompany.com/rest/CreateWidget HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

61
{"Name":"logitech","Type":"mouse","id":"A1B2"}
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if the Data is sent in a series of chunks.

The Content-Length header is omitted in this case and at the beginning of each chunk you need to add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by '\r\n' and then the chunk itself, followed by another '\r\n'.

The terminating chunk is a regular chunk, with the exception that its length is zero. It is followed by the trailer, which consists of a (possibly empty) sequence of entity header fields.

So if you want to get the request body inside the middleware, you could refer to below codes：

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(
                context.Request.Body,
                encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                bufferSize: 1000000,
                leaveOpen: true))
            {
                var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                // Do some processing with body…

                // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            }
            //You could find the contentlength is null
            var re2 = context.Request.ContentLength;
            await next();
        });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That works, I didn't expect the body to automagically get a value just by reading it but it makes sense now that I think about how chunking works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function for this.  It's based on Brando Zhang's awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017470/5405967) above, but I made the code more concise without losing any functionality.

```
private static async Task<string> ExtractRequestBodyAsync(HttpRequest request)
{
    request.EnableBuffering();
    var body = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    request.Body.Position = 0;
    return body;
}
```

By the way, I verified that his technique works for both cases:

1. When `Transfer-Encoding` is `'chunked'`
2. When `Content-Length` is used instead